# Redux, connect method not working. Data not fetched from store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning redux. I have written an application for the same, first time. I am not able to understand why data isnt being fetched from store. Is there anything wrong with my connect call? Please help.

I am getting error that contactsList  is undefined while calling map below, although connect should fetch that list as per my understanding.

ContactCards.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const CardList = ({ contactsList }) => {
  const cardsArray = contactsList.map(contact => (
    <Card
      key={contact.id}
      name={contact.name}
      email={contact.email}
      phone={contact.phone}
      website={contact.website}
      city={contact.address.city}
      companyName={contact.company.name}
      id={contact.id} />
  ));

  return (
    <div className="jumbotron">
      <div className='card-columns'>
        {cardsArray}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { contactsList: state.contactsList };
};

const ContactCards = connect(mapStateToProps)(CardList);

export default ContactCards;
```

Reducer dataReducer

```
import ContactsList from '../components/MockContactsList';
import {loadContacts, updateContacts} from '../Actions/CardActions';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  contactsList: ContactsList
};

 const dataReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {

    case loadContacts:
      return state;

    case updateContacts:
      const updatedItems = state.contactsList.map(item => {
        if(item.id === action.id){
          return { ...item, ...action.payload }
        }
        return item
      })
      return updatedItems;

    default:
      return state;

  }
};

export default dataReducer;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import reducers from './reducers/index';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const store = createStore(reducers, {});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store = {store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
    ,document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

Reducers index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import dataReducer from './dataReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  dataReducer
});
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import reducers from './reducers/index';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const store = createStore(reducers, {});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store = {store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
    ,document.getElementById('root'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: show your reducers/index

Comment: Shat does `import ContactsList from '../components/MockContactsList';` return in your reducer? Are you returning there a component?
If instead of using that you will use empty hash in initial state contactsList will the result change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your store you have a key of `dataReducer`:

```
export default combineReducers({
  dataReducer
});
```

But you're accessing it as `contactsList` here:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { contactsList: state.contactsList };
};
```

So you probably need to have that key in your store instead:

```
export default combineReducers({
  contactsList: dataReducer
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Amr for the quick response! It looks like I certainly need to read some more redux resources to avoid such mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

You must first access your reducer state (dataReducer) **then** its property:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { contactsList: state.dataReducer.contactsList };
};
```